# Proper way to user *args and initialized arguments in a python function

Tags: python, arguments, args

Let's say I have a function

```
def fix_results(parameter_1 =True, *some_kind_of_iterable):

    if parameter_1:
        df = pd.DataFrame(i for i in some_kind_of_iterable if i['count'] == 1)
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame(i for i in some_kind_of_iterable)

    And the some piece of code for df.  

    return df
```

When I run it like:

```
fix_results(*some_results),
```

it works fine. But when I try to run it like

```
fix_results(parameter_1=False,*some_results)
```

i get this error:

```
TypeError: fix_results() got multiple values for keyword argument 'parameter_1'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, the only way to call this function correctly using a `*args` argument is to pass `parameter_1` as positional parameter, i.e. without the `parameter_1=` bit:

```
fix_results(False, *some_results)
```

In Python 3, you could modify your function definition and turn `parameter_1` into a keyword-only parameter:

```
def fix_results(*some_kind_of_iterable, parameter_1=True):
    ....
```

This function can be called by either

```
fix_results(parameter_1=False, *some_results)
```

or

```
fix_results(*some_results, parameter_1=False)
```

Note that your call `fix_results(*some_results)`, which you claim "works fine", probably doesn't do what you expect it to do:  The first element of the iterable will be used as `parameter_1`.

An alternative in Python 2 would be to pass the iterable in as a single parameter, and not use the `*args` syntax:

```
def fix_results(some_kind_of_iterable, parameter_1=True):
    ....
```

This function can now be called like this:

```
fix_results(some_results, parameter_1=False)
```

Comment: So, is there another way to have the same result in order to declare what parameter_1  is for ?  (For python 2.7)

Comment: @GiorgosPerakis I've added a Python 2 alternative to my answer.

Comment: I wanted to use *args instead of a regular argument. But thanks a lot!